# Fill data points within the boundary established by the given points

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions, random

I have the following data points:

```
bound = {{10.`, 
    0.`}, {9.863613034027223`, -1.6459459028073389`}, \
{9.458172417006347`, -3.2469946920468344`}, {8.794737512064891`, \
-4.759473930370735`}, {7.891405093963936`, -6.142127126896678`}, \
{6.77281571625741`, -7.357239106731316`}, {5.469481581224268`, \
-8.371664782625285`}, {4.016954246529695`, -9.157733266550574`}, \
{2.454854871407991`, -9.694002659393304`}, {0.8257934547233232`, \
-9.965844930066698`}, {-0.8257934547233232`, -9.965844930066698`}, \
{-2.454854871407991`, -9.694002659393304`}, {-4.016954246529695`, \
-9.157733266550574`}, {-5.469481581224268`, -8.371664782625285`}, \
{-6.77281571625741`, -7.357239106731316`}, {-7.891405093963936`, \
-6.142127126896678`}, {-8.794737512064891`, -4.759473930370735`}, \
{-9.458172417006347`, -3.2469946920468344`}, {-9.863613034027223`, \
-1.6459459028073389`}, {-10.`, 0.`}, {-10.`, 
    0.42105263157894735`}, {-10.`, 0.8421052631578947`}, {-10.`, 
    1.263157894736842`}, {-10.`, 1.6842105263157894`}, {-10.`, 
    2.1052631578947367`}, {-10.`, 2.526315789473684`}, {-10.`, 
    2.9473684210526314`}, {-10.`, 3.3684210526315788`}, {-10.`, 
    3.789473684210526`}, {-10.`, 4.2105263157894735`}, {-10.`, 
    4.631578947368421`}, {-10.`, 5.052631578947368`}, {-10.`, 
    5.473684210526316`}, {-10.`, 5.894736842105263`}, {-10.`, 
    6.315789473684211`}, {-10.`, 6.7368421052631575`}, {-10.`, 
    7.157894736842105`}, {-10.`, 7.578947368421052`}, {-10.`, 
    8.`}, {-9.863613034027223`, 
    9.64594590280734`}, {-9.458172417006347`, 
    11.246994692046835`}, {-8.794737512064891`, 
    12.759473930370735`}, {-7.891405093963936`, 
    14.142127126896678`}, {-6.77281571625741`, 
    15.357239106731317`}, {-5.469481581224268`, 
    16.371664782625285`}, {-4.016954246529695`, 
    17.157733266550572`}, {-2.454854871407991`, 
    17.694002659393306`}, {-0.8257934547233232`, 
    17.965844930066698`}, {0.8257934547233232`, 
    17.965844930066698`}, {2.454854871407991`, 
    17.694002659393306`}, {4.016954246529695`, 
    17.157733266550572`}, {5.469481581224268`, 
    16.371664782625285`}, {6.77281571625741`, 
    15.357239106731317`}, {7.891405093963936`, 
    14.142127126896678`}, {8.794737512064891`, 
    12.759473930370735`}, {9.458172417006347`, 
    11.246994692046835`}, {9.863613034027223`, 
    9.64594590280734`}, {10.`, 8.`}, {10.`, 
    7.578947368421052`}, {10.`, 7.157894736842105`}, {10.`, 
    6.7368421052631575`}, {10.`, 6.315789473684211`}, {10.`, 
    5.894736842105263`}, {10.`, 5.473684210526316`}, {10.`, 
    5.052631578947368`}, {10.`, 4.631578947368421`}, {10.`, 
    4.2105263157894735`}, {10.`, 3.789473684210526`}, {10.`, 
    3.3684210526315788`}, {10.`, 2.9473684210526314`}, {10.`, 
    2.526315789473684`}, {10.`, 2.1052631578947367`}, {10.`, 
    1.6842105263157894`}, {10.`, 1.263157894736842`}, {10.`, 
    0.8421052631578947`}, {10.`, 0.42105263157894735`}, {10.`, 0.`}};
```

and I `ListPlot` these points as follows.

```
ListPlot[bound, Joined -> False, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

My question is how to fill random points into the shape established by these points? My goal is to get the following image.

[image]

But i need to have a description of the region where random points could be generated.

Thank you.

Comment: The "random points" you show in the figure don't look like points as there seems to be some linear clustering going on.  Is there a secondary process that occurs after a random point is selected?

Comment: yes, i will plot them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
reg = ConvexHullMesh[bound];
pts = RandomPoint[reg, 500];
Show[
 ListPlot[bound
  , Joined -> False
  , AspectRatio -> Automatic
  , PlotStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[8], Blue}
  , PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1]
  , Epilog -> {
    Red, AbsolutePointSize[4]
    , Point@pts
    }
  ]
 , Region[Style[reg, Opacity[0.1, Yellow]]]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Since the points are in order,we can only use `Polygon@bound`.

```
ListPlot[bound, Joined -> False, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[4], 
   Point[RandomPoint[Polygon@bound, 500]], Opacity[.2], 
   Polygon@bound}]
```

[image]

Comment: did i get data point inside the boundary?